# Move ASP.NET WebApi 2.0 controller to separate application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

We have a WebApi 2.0 application with several controllers, one of which is used to relay data.  Due to issues with scalability, we want to move that particular controller out to a separate process so that we can scale it separately from the rest of the application, possibly on a different server altogether.  We don't want to break compatibility though, and until we can get all of the clients updated, we will still have requests being made to the old endpoint that controller sat on.  What is the simplest way to redirect those requests (it must work with GET/POST/DELETE) to the new location?  Does this have to be done within IIS, or is there a way to modify the route?  So far we've tried simply returning a redirect response within the old controller, but this doesn't work properly for POST:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://new/api/endpoint");
        return response;
```

Even if it did, we have some library components that use WebClient with auto-redirect turned off, and those would need to be refactored, which is not ideal.  Is there a guaranteed solution?

Comment: You can use WebClient inside old controller to call the new controller

Comment: Commenting, instead of answering because i'm dodging the original question - have you considering using a different pattern for the controller which you're worried about scaling out separately?  Is it a longer running operation you're concerned about, or the sheer number of incoming requests?

Comment: @Veatch it's a controller used for file transfer, long transfers choke the other connections to the same process, so we are trying to separate it.

Answer (score 1):

A redirect is nothing more than an HTTP response with a particular status code and some extra information.  If your client application isn't going to follow a redirect than that's not an option for solving your problem.

You could have your `Post()` method act as a proxy for the other web service.  As an example, if your first API is at `example.com/Site1` and your second API is at `example.com/Site2` then you could have your client make a request to `Site1` while `Site1` internally makes a request to `Site2`.

Comment: So what you're saying is if the clients are not setup to follow a redirect, then even redirecting at the IIS level is not going to work?  Is there a way to do it through the ASP.NET routing instead, so it doesn't look like a redirect?